# Since Drupal 7.4x I am unable to upload/browse images in civicrm

Tags: kcfinder

kcfinder is not allowing me to browse or upload images. I get this error:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
You must be logged in with proper permissions to edit, add, or delete uploaded images.

I am logged in as User 1. It seems that kcfinder does not know that I am logged in.

[image]

Comment: Note that in Drupal 7, the concept of the Drupal superuser (user/1) is obsolete; you select the admin role from among the standard roles, and can assign it to any number of accounts to it.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that our was a permission issue. I'm on Pantheon so I want able to change the permissions on the directory I was using, so I changed directories for uploads and it worked

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a settings.localtion.php file in your civicrm directory

then have

define('CIVICRM_CONFDIR', 'directory where civicrm.settings.php is');

Comment: I created a file with this: 
<?php
define('CIVICRM_CONFDIR', '/code/sites/default/');
?>

I called the file settings.location.php and also tried calling it settings_location.php

The error still persists

Comment: in your define you want the full path right from the server's root and then ending at sites/default' I don't think you need the ?> at the the end tho

Comment: see here http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=86213657

Comment: The error changed to this : Could not find valid configuration dir, best guess: /code/sites/default/
then We fixed it and corrected the file to this:
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['PRESSFLOW_SETTINGS'])) {
 $env = json_decode($_SERVER['PRESSFLOW_SETTINGS'], TRUE);
 if (!empty($env['conf']['pantheon_binding'])) {
  $pantheon_conf = $env['conf'];
  $civicrm_conf = '/srv/bindings/' . $pantheon_conf['pantheon_binding'] . '/code/sites/default';

  define('CIVICRM_CONFDIR', $civicrm_conf);
 }
}

Now we are back to the old error...